# JSTL EL conditional error

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am using the following conditional check using JSTL but its throwing the error "javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: No function is mapped to the name "fn:length" 
  `<c:choose>

        <c:when test='${fn:length(studentData.rollNumber) == "0"}'>
             Found Nothing
        </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
       Found something
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>`

What am I doing wrong here? I just need to compare the length of roll number.

Comment: You can also just use `${empty studentData.rollNumber}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html), the `fn:length()` only works on `String` (which would return the value of [`String#length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method) and on `Collection` (which would return the value of [`Collection#size()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size%28%29) method).

You however seem to be passing in a **number**. An integer or something. The `fn:length()` doesn't work on numbers and would always give `false`, irrespective of the number's value.

If you want to check if something is `null`, then just do so:

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${studentData.rollNumber == null}">Found Nothing</c:when> 
    <c:otherwise>Found something</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Or if you want to check if the number's value is `0`, then just do

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${studentData.rollNumber == 0}">Found Nothing</c:when> 
    <c:otherwise>Found something</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Note that the `empty` check works equally well and this is regardless of whether it's a number, string or a collection. Anything which is `null` or has a `fn:length()` of `0` would evaluate `true`.

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty studentData.rollNumber}">Found Nothing</c:when> 
    <c:otherwise>Found something</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: BalusC, Sorry I didnt see your reply before. You are correct and its fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

And make condition like the following

```
<c:when test="${fn:length(studentData.rollNumber) == 0}">
```

Comment: Still no even though I have the taglibs present: JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /WEB-INF/jsp/provider/splashPage.jsp: JSPG0095E: Unable to locate the el function length in the tld with uri http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page

Comment: Hit F5, recheck the taglib uri.

Comment: you may want to update your question with details on your application server

Comment: @t0mcat: Look at the error message. Your taglib URI is not the same as in Jigar's answer.

Comment: folks, c:when isnt working at all. To get rid of this I am using c:if now but no matter that 
result its always calling the first condition which returns "no data yet"

Comment: BalusC, these are the three tag libs I am using: <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

Comment: @Jigar: you had the wrong taglib URI in the answer? @t0mcat: what are those semicolons doing there?

Comment: @BalusC No , probably I was adding on so the comment

Comment: @Jigar: in the comment of t0mcat containing the three taglib declarations. @t0mcat: did you also fix the comparison? You're basically comparing an int to a string which would always evaluate `false`.

Comment: BalusC, whats the fix for this? Why the two <c:if> solutions isnt working? because of string n int issue?

Comment: Look at the answer of Jigar how he compares to `0`. Without quotes!

Comment: I am not using quotes        <c:if test="${fn:length(studentData.rollNumber) == 0}">
    Nothing Found
   </c:if>
   
       <c:if test="${fn:length(studentData.rollNumber) > 0}"> 
 Found something for roll num: 
 </c:if>

Comment: Only the first <c:if> executes everytime

Comment: Folks this comment chain is getting long n long... Can I post another question and you all can chime in?